# Working with JQuery inside apex:repeat or apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a code-piece like below where I need to check number of times my picklist values selected as Yes. If this is more than one or zero within this apex:repeat section, I need to show a validation error on UI using JQuery.
Note - AffiliationAccountList here contains more than 10 items every time for me.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!AffiliationAccountList}" var="mAff">
  ........
  <apex:selectList size="1" styleClass="pfClass"  label="Primary Affiliation" value="{!mAff.primaryAffiliation}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!OptionsYesNo}"></apex:selectOptions>
  </apex:selectList> 
<apex:repeat>
```

JQuery used :

```
   var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
   j$(document).ready(function(){
        j$('.pfClass').change(function(){
        alert('Last Name = ' +  j$('.pfClass').val());
        });
    });
```

I was trying to use class selector assuming there is no way to have a static/same id for my selectlist. Please suggest the best way to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case you could get all elements with a particular value and count the number of objects returned:

```
function checkAffiliationLimit()
{
    if (jQuery('.pfClass[value="Yes"]').length > 10)
       //Display error
}
```

You could also use a closure and iterate over your items (leaving this here in case someone has a similar issue that can't use the first solution):

```
function checkAffiliationLimit()
{
    var numChecked = 0;
    jQuery('.pfClass').each(
        function()
        {
            if (this.val() == 'Yes')
                ++numChecked;
        }
    )
    if (numChecked > 10)
        //display error
}
```

In general, the ids of elements inside `<apex:repeat>` all end in their iteration number (0, 1, 2...), which may be useful if you need an element from a specific index.